# Where is the AVD generated SQLite file?

Tags: android

I have to run some code to create a SQLite database application in the virtual machine. Now, I want to find it that the system generated the SQLite files in what place?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's here
/data/data/your.package.name/databases/

Comment: I used the adb shell commands, and also according to this directory,But I don't know what should be ahead of the path！

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window menu > Show view > Other > Android > File Explorer.
In File explorer go to data (folder) > data > your.package.name > databases

Comment: How look for this part path："Window menu > Show view > Other > Android > File Explorer". My operation system is windows 8,I'm sorry,I don't know how to find!

Comment: u have to look in eclipse...

Comment: Well,I know you said the path now.thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It should be created in mnt/sdcard/... (In the SD Card of your virtual android device)
It's somewhere in there.
And you should give this path to your SqliteConnection.